# How do I pass an objective bound to Gurobi?

Tags: linear-programming, gurobi, nonlinear-programming, quadratic-programming, yalmip

I have a non-convex Quadratic Programming over unite simplex set. I have a valid lower bound on the objective function (goal is minimization problem).
If I add a constraint like
$$f(x)\geq lower~bound,$$
the solver time is increased, since I add a non-convex constraint!
is there any efficient way to use a lower bound in the input when we use Gurobi as a solver (in yalmip)?

Comment: See https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/419/feeding-known-lower-bounds-to-solvers

Answer (score 2):

There's a [cutoff](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/cutoff.html) parameter that may help.
Another approach, though may or may not work is to try with $Z(x)$ $=$ lower_bound$+f(x)$

Comment: I am not fully aware of that but a Gurobi engineer did post this: https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360048430691-How-do-I-pass-an-objective-bound-to-Gurobi-. But then cutoff parameter can be queried and modified as another staff member confirmed here: https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360065230572-How-to-set-objective-upper-bound-